# How to contain tab control from buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have the following code chunk (apologies for the block)

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="439" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1171" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Margin="0,0,0,-1" >
    <TabControl Height="419" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="1151">
        <TabItem x:Name="MainTab" Header="Main">
        <Grid>

            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="741" Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="118" Margin="10,91,0,0">
                <Controls:Tile Title="Add Shift" 
                TiltFactor="2"
                Width="100" Height="100" 
                Count="1" Margin="0" Click="TileTabControl">
                </Controls:Tile>

                <Controls:Tile Title="Recorded Shifts" 
                TiltFactor="2"
                Width="136" Height="100" 
                Count="2" Margin="0" Canvas.Left="105">
                </Controls:Tile>

                <Controls:Tile Title="Details Of Pay" 
                TiltFactor="2"
                Width="136" Height="100" 
                Count="3" Margin="0" Canvas.Left="246">
                </Controls:Tile>

                <Controls:Tile Title="Account Settings" 
                TiltFactor="2"
                Width="158" Height="100" 
                Count="4" Margin="0" Canvas.Left="387">
                </Controls:Tile>

                <Controls:Tile Title="View Shifts By Month" 
                TiltFactor="2"
                Width="191" Height="100" 
                Count="5" Margin="0" Canvas.Left="550">
                </Controls:Tile>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="RecordedShifts" Header="Recorded Shifts">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="PayDetails" Header="Pay Details">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="AccountSettings" Header="Account Settings">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="ShiftsByMonth" Header="Shifts By Month">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="NewShift" Header="New Shift ">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Canvas>
```

I'm trying to figure out a method to send information to the same handler which will control the changing of tabs. What i've got

```
    private void TileTabControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e,string U)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(U.ToString()); <!-- Test if U is correctly set-->
    }
```

From this method, i plan to change the selected tab by doing something along the lines of:

```
    private void TileTabControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e,string U)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(U.ToString());
        U.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

Which will then switch to the correct tab. I feel if this method is possible, it'll minimize the duplicated functions voids which will serve one purpose which is to switch to different tabs.

I have tried:

```
Count="1" Margin="0" Click="TileTabControl(MainTab)">
```

Which returned:

> Error 1   Click="TileTabControl(test)" is not valid.
>   'AddNewShiftTileClick(test)' is not a valid event handler method name.
>   Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.

I have researched into google on how to do something along these lines, but from what i've discovered is the basic questions which ask about changing tab control from the control it's self, which churns out code snippets along the lines of:

```
TabControl.Tabs[TabNumber].IsSelected=true;
```

Which when attempting to modify and include into my current code set turned out with no avail.

There is the basic approach which is to create a new event handler for each Tile click to switch tabs, but I feel this would give a messy look to the back-end C# coding.

Is there any different approach or a scheme which I could impliment to minimize the duplicated event handlers to perform a single purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have managed to find a work around, before further additions to the tab control, I have made the following changes:

```
 <Controls:Tile Title="Add Shift" 
    TiltFactor="2"
    Width="100" Height="100" 
    Count="1" Margin="0" Tag="NewShift" Click="TileTabControl">
 </Controls:Tile>
```

With the addition of the `tag` element, to give a parameter/value within the `sender` object & validate as such:

```
var Type = (Button)sender;
MessageBox.Show(Type.Tag.ToString());
```

Which casts the Sender object to a button, which will inturn allow me to get the value parsed inside the `tag` element, turn to string & print out in a textbox. Which after data manipulations, looks roughly like so:

```
    private void TileTabControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Tab = (Button)sender;
        //MessageBox.Show(Type.Tag.ToString());
        switch (Tab.Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "NewShift":
                break;
            case "RecordedShifts":
                break;
            case "DetailsOfPay":
                break;
            case "AccountSettings":
                break;
            case "ShiftsByMonth":
                break;
        }
    }
```